# 9V (6F22) Lithium battery recharging

Tags: lithium-ion

Right now i am thinking about changing all my alkaline 9V blocks to lithium blocks. 
But I'm not sure how to load the cells. Sure...I could buy a charger...but I have enough chargers and a bench power supply at home already :P

I read that the 9V Li-ion blocks have a nominal voltage of 7.4 V and a maximum voltage of ~8.4 V. So it just seems to be two Li-ion batteries connected in series.

But I don't see any possibility of balancing on the blocks. Are the cells internally balanced? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can charge Li-Ion "9V" batteries by a CC/CV power from a bench supply (8.4V and 150-200mA). I have a battery like this and have charged it using this method several times.

As you note the problem would be unbalanced cells. There's nothing much you can do about it, you can only count on the cells being closely matched during manufacture, but of course it's suboptimal.

Comment: You can, but you have to be careful.  A mistake can cause a fire.

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer two 14500 cells nowadays. Same voltage, same capacity, but you can charge them separately.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I always charg li-ion and li-polymer batteries inside a metal case to protect me form a eventual fire. 
But - according to ~ 1.5mm additional length - the 14500s don't fit into every 9V bay, do they?

Comment: In work we've been using enclosures for electronic devices, that have a built-in battery bay. The bay can fit either a PP3 (9-volt) or 2×AA, and has arrangements for both. On some gadgets we used 9V for simplicity, but for more power-hungry devices we use 2×AA alkaline, or, if rechargeability would be useful, 2×14500 (which is the same form-factor as AA). YMMV, you are correct that some bays that accommodate 9V only won't accept 2×14500 if the space is tight and the compartment is cramped.

Comment: I measured my two most important battery bays. Both are too small for the 14500 cells. 
And i found a disassembly picture of the EBL 9V 600 mAh batteries. They are acutally using a small BMS including undervoltage protection. 
I oredered four of them and will give it a try.

Comment: Undervoltage, yes. But do they also do balancing?